# The `success` and `ready` event for HTML5 `<audio>` tag?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, event-handling, dom-events

Here is my code (coffeescript):

```
toVoice = new Audio("myVoice.mp3")
toVoice.addEventListener("ended", ->console.log("ended"))
toVoice.addEventListener("error", ->console.log("error"))
toVoice.addEventListener("success", ->console.log("success"))
toVoice.addEventListener("ready", ->console.log("ready"))
```

I want to show a message when:

1. the remote audio file is downloadable
2. the audio file is playable

I found the `ended` and `error` eventListener works well, but the `success` and `ready` eventListener doesn't work.

I tried to find a MDN documentation about all the available events for `Audio` tag/object but I didn't find one..

Does anyone have ideas about how to register a callback to detect whether an audio is valid and playable?

Answer (score 5):

There are no success or ready [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) for [media element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

I think you can try `loadstart` and `loadeddata`

```
toVoice = new Audio("myVoice.mp3")
toVoice.addEventListener("ended", ->console.log("ended"))
toVoice.addEventListener("error", ->console.log("error"))
toVoice.addEventListener("canplay", ->console.log("canplay"))
toVoice.addEventListener("loadeddata", ->console.log("loadeddata"))
```

Comment: the `canplay` event can probably replace what OP thought was the `ready` event.

Comment: Just to clarify things, addingEventListener are not Promise-like. It means if the src associated with the Audio object is fully loaded before adding an EventListener for the 'loadeddata' event, the function won't get called. to get around this, just construct an empty object `var myaudio = new Audio();` -> create the EventListener -> and then provide the src `myaudio.src = 'myVoice.mp3'`